# Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/icons/KeyboardArrowUp'

Tags: material-ui

I was trying to use **material-ui**, scroll to see button app bar. I did install `material-ui/core` as well but still giving an error

> Can't resolve @material-ui/core/icons/KeyboardArrowUp

Answer (score 2):

You need to install **Material UI icons package** first. Material UI icons are present in package **@material-ui/icons**

```sh
// with npm
npm install @material-ui/icons

// with yarn
yarn add @material-ui/icons
```

Then *import icons* like

```js
import KeyboardArrowUpIcon from '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowUp' ;
```

Comment: @niro I did that and it shows "Cannot find module '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowUpIcon' or its corresponding type declarations". I was thinking that the package no longer existed but after seeing this question i know it does, so any ideias why it still doesnt work?